# free heap block modified after it was freed

Tags: c

I am receiving the notorious *"free heap block modified after it was freed"* message on data=(LPBYTE) malloc(MAX_VALUE_DATA);. [This stackoverflow thread suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137275/heap-error-in-c) that it is because I am freeing something incorrectly. And indeed if the free(data) near the bottom is uncommented, this error returns and if it is commented - goes away. How am I freeing it wrong?

```
// Enumerate the key values. 

        if (cValues) 
        {
            printf( "\nNumber of values: %d\n", cValues);
            LPBYTE data;            
            DWORD size;
            data=(LPBYTE) malloc(MAX_VALUE_DATA);
            messageProvider mp={(TCHAR*) currentRoot,NULL,NULL,NULL};
            BOOL anyGoodValues=FALSE;
            for (i=0, retCode=ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++) 
            { 
                cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 
                achValue[0] = '\0'; 
                ZeroMemory(data,MAX_VALUE_DATA);
                //data=(LPBYTE) malloc(MAX_VALUE_DATA);
                size=MAX_VALUE_DATA;
                retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, 
                    achValue, 
                    &cchValue, 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL,
                    data,
                    &size);

                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
                { 
                    _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) '%s'\n"), i+1, achValue); 
                    BOOL valFound=FALSE;
                    if (_tcscmp(achValue,_T("ParameterMessageFile")) == 0 ){

                        mp.ParameterMessageFile=(TCHAR *)data;
                        anyGoodValues=TRUE;
                        valFound=TRUE;
                    }
                    if (_tcscmp(achValue,_T("CategoryMessageFile")) == 0 ){

                        mp.CategoryMessageFile=(TCHAR *)data;
                        anyGoodValues=TRUE;
                        valFound=TRUE;
                    }
                    if (_tcscmp(achValue,_T("EventMessageFile")) == 0 ){
                        mp.ParameterMessageFile=(TCHAR *)data;          
                        anyGoodValues=TRUE;
                        valFound=TRUE;
                    }
                    if(!valFound){
                        //free(data);
                    }
                }

            }
            if(anyGoodValues)               
                mpArray[mpIndex++]=mp;      
        }
```

Comment: When you moved your malloc outside the loop, you left free within.  Move free out as well.  You don't want to malloc/free over and over within a loop.  It's very inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You allocate once, but free inside a loop. In the future, this sort of thing will be easier to find if you always set your pointers to `NULL` after calling `free()` on them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the free() outside the loop; at next iteration through the loop RegEnumValue is using data after it is freed.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the "default" value for /Zp compiler option ("struct member alignment" in C/C++ Code generation) 
in your code and in all the the libraries.

For an explanation, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444115/1997864